# how yara express a string at half of a file

Tags: python, malware-detection, yara

I've written a Yara rule to search a string at half of a file.
It's like this:

```
rule test 
{
   strings:
        $tag1 = "<%" ascii wide
        $tag2= "%>" wide ascii
   condition:
        ($tag1 in (0..100) and $tag2 in ((filesize*0.5)..filesize))
         
}
```

I meet this error:
`wrong type for range's lower bound`

how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example for first 100 bytes

```
import "cuckoo"

rule test {
    strings:
        $tag1 = "<%" ascii wide
        $tag2 = "%>" ascii wide

    condition:
        cuckoo.file.size <= 1048576 and
        $tag1 at 0..100 and
        $tag2 at (cuckoo.file.size / 2) .. cuckoo.file.size
}
```

Comment: sorry, it does not work.  This error occurs : 'undefined string "$filesize"'.  ‘filesize’ is a internal variables in yara

Comment: @Bourne813 you have the define the filesize first 
$filesize = yourfile.size or filesize = 1024 # for example

Comment: @Bourne813 please check the modified code.